# To Convert Rotation Vector to Rotation Matrix, the Rotation Vector Must be Unit?

Tags: rotations

I have a following formula to convert rotation vector($K\in \Bbb R^3$) to rotation matrix ($R \in SO(3)$) where $I$ is an identity matrix and K could be uniquely acquired from the conversion of an **unit** vector  $k$ which corresponds to the axis of rotation according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)

> $R = I + (\sin{\theta}) K + (1-\cos{\theta})K^2$

What I hold as of now as a dataset is a camera parameter which represents the axis of rotation, but those are not unit vectors. Is it okay for me just use the parameter which **is not unit** with above formula to get $R$?

The dataset is given in [this link](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/bundle_adjustment.html)

Comment: In a word: no. Read the derivation of the formula on that page to understand why not. It’s a simple matter to normalize a vector.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. The axis of rotation for Rodrigues formula must be unit vector.

However, from the link that you posted I can see that the norm of the "rotation vector" $k$ is the angle $\theta = \|k\|$. So the "rotation vector" is encoding compactly the axis and the angle of rotation.

So for using Rodrigues formula your parameters are the axis of rotation $k/\|k\|$ and the angle of rotation $\theta = \|k\|$.